# Laravel 5.2 Cron job doesn't work

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-5

I want to create a cron job for test.
When i run the cron in log file appear the line but after not. I set cron job every minute.

I used php artisan schedule:run ..

Command dbTS

```
public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('Functioneaza !');
    }
```

Console Kernel

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('dbTS:demo')
                  ->everyMinute();
    }

  protected $commands = [
         Commands\Inspire::class,
         Commands\dbTS::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Are you running this cron manually by typing `php artisan schedule:run` or do you have the actual cronjob running? `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: php artisan:schedule:run in terminal phpstorm.

Comment: now i try * * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 in terminal.. @Björn